# VueJS Component Registration

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I created a global component which I wanted to quickly test within my code. But VueJS complains that the component is not registered. I thought when I create components like below, this should already work?

I used for a test the BULMA CSS framework and copy&pasted a component I wanted to test. So in the HTML code I will use:

```
<div id="app">
    <message title="Hello world" body="test"></message>
</div>
```

The error I get is:

> unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

```
Vue.component('message', {
    props: ['title', 'body'],
    template: `
<article class="message">
            <div class="message-header">
                <p>{{title}}</p>
                <button class="delete"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="message-body">
                {{body}}
            </div>
        </article>`
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        responders: [],
        incidents: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getIncidents();
    },

    methods: { (...)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2re6qv6h/#&togetherjs=BnB0KhQdLU

**Update**

The code is embedded in my laravel code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MEDIFAKTOR - @yield('title') </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.2.0/vue-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        @include('layouts.navigation')
        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
            <!-- Page wrapper -->
            @include('layouts.topnavbar')
            <!-- Main view  -->
<div id="app">
    <my-message title="Hello world" body="test"></my-message>
</div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            @include('layouts.footer')
        </div>
        <!-- End page wrapper-->
    </div>
    <!-- End wrapper-->
  @section('scripts')
@show
</body>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**The Full VueJS Code**

```
Vue.component('my-message', {
    props: ['title', 'body'],

    data() {
        return {
            isVisible: true
        };
    },

    template: `
<article class="my-message" v-show="true">
            <div class="message-header">
                <p>{{title}}</p>
                <button type="button" @click="hideModal">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="message-body">
                {{body}}
            </div>
        </article>`,

    methods: {
        hideModal() {
            this.isVisible = false;
        }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        responders: [],
        incidents: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getIncidents();
    },

    methods: {
        getIncidents: function() {
            console.log('getIncidents');
            var self = this;
            this.$http.get('/api/v1/incidents').then(function(response) {
                // set data on vm
                console.log(response.data);
                var incidentsReceived = response.data.data.map(function (incident) {
                    return incident;
                });
                Vue.set(self, 'incidents', incidentsReceived);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `article`, how is this defined, possible to create a fiddle reproducing it?

Comment: Updated my question. it is just a component used from BULMA CSS Framework for testing

Comment: I just wonder why the component is not recognized even if it is a global component in the same JS file defined

Comment: possible to create a fiddle reproducing it?

Comment: added a fiddle. Strange thing is, it is being displayed in fiddle, but not in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing your article's class name `<article class="message">` to  `<article class="my-message">`

Comment: nope, still the same error. It seems like my global components are not recognized at all

Comment: Can you upload full code of `app` and care about script caching?. I ran your code worked fine

Comment: Did compile again? `npm run dev` for laravel 5.4 and `gulp` for laravel 5.3

Comment: Yep did that as well

Comment: oh... wait... I checked the source file.. I re-compiled, but the browser still shows the old JS script file. it doesnt seem to update in the browser

Comment: this is strange.. how can I fix this? I am working on a local machine for development, running Laravel on homestead. I run the gulp command and it works well, but when I update the browser the changes are not being used

Comment: Try by disabling caching https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Version of Laravel that you are using, it already comes with Vue baked in, and it attaches it directly to the window. My guess is that your app is running and the Vue reference is being overridden by the Laravel instance where you are not registering your component. To be sure, remove the bottom script tag in your html, `<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

As well it looks like you are registering your component just fine. If anything you can add the `is=""` attribute to your component to explicitly tell it which component it is. Its a bit redundant if you have called it my-message, but it does provide some clarity for people that it is a Vue component. Ultimately, that will be up to your and your team's digression.

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of trolling through SO answers I finally discovered that the issue lies in Chrome not updating the `app.js` file. Do a hard refresh in your browser and it should take the error away. Try [disabling browser cache completely](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache) if you're so inclined.